# error: unable to read property list from file: /Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, plist, ios-camera

I am trying to build my react native app in Xcode but I keep getting this error. I know this means my plist is probably configured improperly, but it is next to impossible to find the proper syntax or documentation for these files. I have added 5 things to the default `plist` that gets generated when running `npx react-native init <app-name>`. They look as follows...

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Kidz-n-Motion access to your camera</string>

    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Kidz-n-Motion access to add to your Photos</string>

    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Kidz-n-Motion access to your Camera Roll</string>

    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Kidz-n-Motion access to your microphone during recording<string>

    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Gilroy-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-ExtraBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-Heavy.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-SemiBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-Thin.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-UltraLight.ttf</string>
        <string>Lato-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Lato-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Lato-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Lato-Semibold.ttf</string>
        <string>LeagueSpartan-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>LeagueSpartan-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>LeagueSpartan-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>LeagueSpartan-SemiBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Spartan-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Spartan-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Spartan-ExtraBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Spartan-ExtraLight.ttf</string>
        <string>Spartan-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Spartan-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Spartan-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Spartan-SemiBold.ttf</string>
        <string>Spartan-Thin.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

I'm nearly positive the `UIFonts` are proper, I've built the app with the in the3 `plist` before, meaning its almost certainly the Camera/Mic permissions, however I copied those off of their respective documentation, so I'm not sure what the fix here would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being two typo's that I must have fat-fingered in somehow while copying.

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Kidz-n-Motion access to your camera</string>

    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Kidz-n-Motion access to add to your Photos</string>

    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Kidz-n-Motion access to your Camera Roll</string>

    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Kidz-n-Motion access to your microphone during recording<string> //needs to be </string>
```

You can more precisely see what's screwing with your plist **if you attempt to open the Info file inside of your Xcode workspace**
You can find that option here...
[image]

If it opens up, your plist is configured properly. If it does not open, it will report back which line is breaking